UniswapV3 docs: tickToWord()
Could someone kindly explain, what the following function from the UniswapV3 docs actually do?
function tickToWord(tick: number): number {
 let compressed = Math.floor(tick / tickSpacing)
  if (tick < 0 && tick % tickSpacing !== 0) {
    compressed -= 1
  }
  return tick >> 8
}

Sorry, when it sounds like a stupid question, but i dont get it.
I mean, the only thing which is actually done is, bit shifting the Tick by 8 to the right. Which should of course gives the word position.
But what is the compressed value for, when it is not even returned nor combined with the word position? Even though, this would make no sense, because every negative number bit shifted to the right or left stays a negative number.
So what do i miss here?
